# spring framework spring-data-redis serialization exception

Tags: java, jedis, spring-data-redis

I am very novice to Java programming. I am C# developer. I was working on one of the small project where we want to use the redis cache instead of ehcache.

We are using spring.data.redis version 2.2.3.RELEASE and redis.client.jedis version 3.2.0.

Here is my redisconf class which contains RedisTemplate as well:

```
public class RedisConf {
    private String REDIS_HOSTNAME = "localhost";
    private int REDIS_PORT = 6379;

    protected JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(REDIS_HOSTNAME, REDIS_PORT);
        JedisClientConfiguration jedisClientConfiguration = JedisClientConfiguration.builder().usePooling().build();
        JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory(configuration,jedisClientConfiguration);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory;
    }


    public RedisTemplate<String,Element> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<String,Element> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String,Element>();
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
        redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

Here is how instantiate RedisConf class:

```
RedisConf rf = new RedisConf();
RedisTemplate<String, Element> redisTemplate = rf.redisTemplate();
redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().ping();
cache = new RedisDelegate(redisTemplate);
```

Here is my RedisDeligate class where I do all my get and put operation:

```
public class RedisDelegate implements Cache {

    private final RedisTemplate<String,Element> redisTemplate;
    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisDelegate.class);
    private static String REDIS_KEY = "Redis";

    public RedisDelegate(RedisTemplate<String,Element> redisTemplate) {
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "my-redis";
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNativeCache() {
        return this.redisTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public Element get(Object key) {

        try {
            LOGGER.debug("Key is: {}", key);
            Object element = this.redisTemplate.opsForHash().get(REDIS_KEY, key);
            LOGGER.debug("element Object is: {}", element);
            return (element == null) ? null : (Element) element;
            //return (Element) this.redisTemplate.opsForHash().get(REDIS_KEY, key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void put(Element element) {
        this.redisTemplate.opsForHash().put(REDIS_KEY, element.key(), element);
    }

    @Override
    public void evict(Object key) {
        this.redisTemplate.opsForHash().delete(REDIS_KEY, key);  
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        redisTemplate.execute((RedisCallback<Object>) connection -> {
            connection.flushDb();
            return null;
        });
    }
}
```

Here is CacheElement Object that I am trying to put in the cache which implements Serializable as seen below:

```
public class CacheElement implements Element, Serializable {
.
.
.
}
```

When I try to put an object into cache, it fails with an error that serialization failed. I know there is some problem with my RedisTemplate but I can't seen to figure out. Here is the error I am receiving:

> Cannot serialize; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException:
>   Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception
>   is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a
>   Serializable payload but received an object of type
>   [io.gravitee.policy.cache.resource.CacheElement]

**EDIT**

I am trying to store the instance of CacheElement class into Redis:

```
public class CacheElement implements Element {

    private final String key;

    private final CacheResponse response;

    private int timeToLive = 0;

    public CacheElement(String key, CacheResponse response) {
        this.key = key;
        this.response = response;
    }

    public int getTimeToLive() {
        return timeToLive;
    }

    public void setTimeToLive(int timeToLive) {
        this.timeToLive = timeToLive;
    }

    @Override
    public Object key() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public Object value() {
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    public int timeToLive() {
        return timeToLive;
    }
}
```

CacheResponse object contains Buffer.

```
public class CacheResponse {

    private int status;

    private HttpHeaders headers;

    private Buffer content;

    public Buffer getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(Buffer content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
        return headers;
    }

    public void setHeaders(HttpHeaders headers) {
        this.headers = headers;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

I would like to serialize this CacheElement object and store it in Redis. 
I also would like to deserialize it on get operation.

I will appreciate help fixing this issue. As I mentioned, I am not a Java developer. I am coming from C# and visual studio world.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please implement your paypload object class with Serializable interface

Comment: Zubair, if you see CacheElement class implementation above, it already implements Serializable. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Hi Andy you can override writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) method, please refer to https://www.baeldung.com/java-serialization